# python selecting submatrix leaving dimensions unchanged

Tags: python, matrix

Just a curiosity, is there a way from a matrix A:

```
A = [ [100, 200, 300, 400],
      [111, 222, 333, 444],
      [555, 666, 777, 888],
      [500, 600, 700, 800] ]
```

to obtain a matrix B that looks like the following:

```
B = [ [nan, nan, nan, nan],
      [nan, 222, 333, nan],
      [nan, 666, 777, nan],
      [nan, nan, nan, nan] ]
```

without using loops/cycles? Because simple cropping obviously changes the former matrix dimensions, producing:

```
B = A[1:3,1:3]
>>> B = [ [222, 333],
          [666, 777] ]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This raises TypeError, maybe you mean numpy arrays?

Comment: Yeah, I skipped that, but they are np.arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of nan's and then assign the values you want from A.

```
B = np.empty(A.shape)
B[:] = np.nan
B[1:3,1:3] = A[1:3,1:3]
print(B)

[[  nan   nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan  222.  333.   nan]
 [  nan  666.  777.   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan   nan]]
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up with something similar... but I was wondering whether there was an "opposite" way to select entries. I mean, "3:5" selects all values WITHIN 3 and 5... is there something like "3*5" selecting all values EXCEPT those within 3 and 5?

Comment: @urgeo didn't you want the intersection? then look at my answer

Comment: That looks like a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Think you want the intersection

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([ [100, 200, 300, 400],
      [111, 222, 333, 444],
      [555, 666, 777, 888],
      [500, 600, 700, 800] ])

B = numpy.array([ [222, 333],
          [666, 777]])

C = numpy.zeros((4,4))
C[:] = numpy.nan
C[1:3, 1:3] = numpy.ones((2,2))

print C * A
```

Output is

```
[[  nan   nan   nan   nan]
[  nan  222.  333.   nan]
[  nan  666.  777.   nan]
[  nan   nan   nan   nan]]
```